# Remove comma after optional argument in Natbib

Tags: bibtex, natbib

I want to be able to add optional arguments surrounding my references with Natbib, using `\citep [see][for review]{besnard2012reconsolidation}`, but my output is

> (see Besnard et al., 2012, for review)

I need to remove the comma after the year, so that it says

> (see Besnard et al., 2012 for review)

Here is a MWE bib file (`mwebib.bib`)

```
\begin{thebibliography}

@article{besnard2012reconsolidation,
  title={Reconsolidation of memory: a decade of debate},
  author={Besnard, Antoine and Caboche, Jocelyne and Laroche, Serge},
  journal={Progress In Neurobiology},
  volume={99},
  number={1},
  pages={61--80},
  year={2012},
  publisher={Elsevier}
}  

\end{thebibliography}
```

and the .tex file

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[round]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{chicago}

\begin{document}

Memories are vulnerable to disruption after their retrieval \citep [see][for review]{besnard2012reconsolidation}.

\bibliography{mwebib}

\end{document}
```

I don't mind using a different referencing package or not being able have commas after optional arguments for the rest of the document.

I don't want to say (for review see Besnard et al., 2012) or (see Besnard et al., (2012) for review), but one of these might have to do if it's not possible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Natbib sets the punctuation before the post-note with the key `notesep` in `\setcitestyle`.  So to make it a space instead of comma-space, just put in the preamble

```
 \setcitestyle{notesep={ }}
```

Also, do not put `\begin...\end` in your `.bib` file.